# Pass EditText value to ListView from two different activities

Tags: android-studio, listview, android-edittext

appreciate if you can help me here.
I am creating a To Do List, where the ListView is in the MainToDoList Activity with a "Add a new Task" button that takes the user to the second activity.

In the second activity, there is a Edit Text field where user can input the title of the task. Two buttons are "Save" and "Cancel"

My question is, how to pass the edit text value after pressing the save button to display it into the listview in the first activity.

First Activity:

```
public class Todolistactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private ListView list;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.todolistactivity);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.addTask);

        list = findViewById(R.id.task_list);
    }

  private void addTask() {
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(Todolistactivity.this, EditToDo.class));
                }
            });
        }

Second Activity:


public class EditToDo extends Todolistactivity {
    private static final String TAG = "EditToDo";

    private Button save;
    private Button cancel;
    private EditText title;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_taskedit);
        save = findViewById(R.id.saveTask);
        cancel = findViewById(R.id.cancelTask);
        title = findViewById(R.id.taskTitle);

        saveButton();
        cancelButton();
    }


   private void saveButton(){

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent backToDo = new Intent 
                  (getBaseContext(),Todolistactivity.class);

                String titleEntered = title.getText().toString();
               backToDo.putExtra("task", titleEntered);
                startActivity(backToDo);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startActivityForResult` 
in your `Todolistactivity` class

```
  private void addTask() {
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                   startActivityForResult(new Intent(Todolistactivity.this, EditToDo.class), 100); // 100 is request code.
                }
            });
        } 
//...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("task");
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

In Your `EditToDo` class

```
  private void saveButton(){

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               String titleEntered = title.getText().toString();
               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.putExtra("task", titleEntered);
               setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
               finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! I followed your instructions step by step but the edit text is still not showing up in the todolist listview. Should I link this to the listview ?

Comment: add the result to your listview. or log it to see if you're getting the data or not